# Assign new class to label when it's input area has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to assign a new class to a label when it's corresponding input element has focus.

I have a form with 10 input fields and 10 labels for each.

```js
const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
console.log(inputFields);
jQuery(inputFields).on('focus', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
    if (jQuery(inputFields[i]).hasFocus) {
      jQuery(inputFields[i].closest('label')).addClass(' active');
      console.log('hello Wurst');
    } else {
      jQuery(inputFields[i].closest('label')).removeClass(' active');
      console.log('hello secondWurst');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5  first_col">
  <div data-field-wrapper="fld_1854024" class="form-group" id="fld_1854024_1-wrap">
    <label id="fld_1854024Label" for="fld_1854024_1" class="control-label">City</label>
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" data-field="fld_1854024" class=" form-control" id="fld_1854024_1" name="fld_1854024" value="" data-type="text" aria-labelledby="fld_1854024Label">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to grab all of the form input elements into a const, then loop through each to see if it has focus. If that particular one has focus, then I want to give the label for that field (and only that field) an additional CSS class.

How do I look for the input that has the cursor focus, and apply a new class to that input's label?

Comment: don't use spaces in your classes for a start - and what is `.hasFocus` ? how is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

This is DOM traversal and is easy with jQuery - on focussing the input - go up to the nearest form-group using .closest() and then down to the nearest label within that form-group, using.find().

Note the line that removes the active class from all labels - this prevents you needing to know which was previously active and ensures that only the currently focussed input's label gets the active class.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').on('focus',function(){
    $('label').removeClass('active');
     $(this).closest('.form-group').find('label').addClass('active');
  });
})
```

```css
.col-sm-5 {
  margin: 16px;
}

label.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5  first_col">
  <div data-field-wrapper="fld_1854024" class="form-group" id="fld_1854024_1-wrap">
    <label id="fld_1854024Label" for="fld_1854024_1" class="control-label">City</label>
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" data-field="fld_1854024" class=" form-control" id="fld_1854024_1" name="fld_1854024" value="" data-type="text" aria-labelledby="fld_1854024Label">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-5  second_col">
  <div data-field-wrapper="fld_1854025" class="form-group" id="fld_1854025_1-wrap">
    <label id="fld_1854025Label" for="fld_1854025_1" class="control-label">State</label>
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" data-field="fld_1854025" class=" form-control" id="fld_1854025_1" name="fld_1854025" value="" data-type="text" aria-labelledby="fld_1854025Label">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that worked for me. I ended up having to alter it to also look to see if an input has a value after leaving since the styles move the label text from a placeholder position upward and over the input. Thanks.